# How can i run speaker wire from my garage to rec room tha that are side by side through the wall

Tags: home-theater

I need some help. Please how can I wire my home theater speakers so I can be in the garage or rec room the spaces are right next to each on the ground level.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see the proper way to say "thanks".

Answer (score 0):

Use an appropriately classified speaker cable for in wall use, such as one marked CL-2 or CL-3.

Or if your question is more on the mechanics, you'll need to make some holes in the walls.

Comment: Or do a bluetooth or similar connection, though that will require more hardware.

Comment: Thanks but for speakers I am not a fan of Bluetooth . I have done it before but it has been a while and I went under the rug and along the base boards but not to a different room I guess a few small holes couldn't hurt and some creativity to cover the hole will work. Thank you for the help.